# JQuery triggering fadeIn and fadeOut on menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Demo - https://jsfiddle.net/jhhpLapv/1/

```
// Main Script For Ciel Viole

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.client-link').click(function() {
          $('.navbar').slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
```

When triggering the hamburger menu, I want the menu links to fadein and subsequently fadeout when the menu is closed. I am very new to this and about as far as I have gotten. How can I listen to the event to trigger the fade in the first time the menu is clicked, and fade out the second time it is clicked?

Comment: there is .fadeIn(), fadeOut() function you can use to achieve that :)

Comment: @JF-Mechs How would I call that for the navbar-links simultaneously alongside  $('.navbar').slideToggle("fast");?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you can try . [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jhhpLapv/2/)

I just updated your code with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $navbar = $('.navbar');
  $('.client-link').click(function() {
    if (!$navbar.hasClass("active")) {
        $navbar.fadeIn("slow").addClass("active");
    }
    else {
        $navbar.fadeOut("slow").removeClass("active");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.client-link').click(function() {
      if($('.navbar').is(':visible')){
        $('.navbar').fadeOut("fast");
      }else{
        $('.navbar').fadeIn("fast");
      }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Always try css based animations. They are very smooth and easy to implement.

Here is how. Instead of calling `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` just add a class to the targeted element. Then in css you can use `transition: all 0.3s ease-in;`(or any other preferable values) to create a transition. Below is just an example using your code. You can make it way, way better than this.

```js
// Main Script For Ciel Viole

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.client-link').click(function() {
    $('.navbar').toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.client-item {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
}
.client-link {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #c5c5c5;
}
.client-link:hover {
  color: #151515;
  -webkit-transition: color 2s ease;
  transition: color 2s ease;
}
.navbar {
  display: none;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .3s;
  animation-delay: .3s;
}
.about-header {
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 34px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
.values {
  background-image: url('../images/infinity-bg.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
  color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 15rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
.title {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: .4rem;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
.title a {
  color: #767676;
}
.content-section {
  padding: 1rem 0;
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
}
.navbar-list {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
}
.navbar-item {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar-link {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  letter-spacing: .2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0 25px 0 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 6.5rem;
  color: #7c7c7c;
  font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif !important;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
.navbar-link:hover {
  color: #000000;
  -webkit-transition: color 2s ease;
  transition: color 2s ease;
}
.navbar-link-left {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  letter-spacing: .2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0 0 0 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 6.5rem;
  color: #7c7c7c;
  font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif !important;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
.navbar-link-left:hover {
  color: #000000;
  -webkit-transition: color 2s ease;
  transition: color 2s ease;
}
/* Roy's override */

.navbar {
  display: block;
  width: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  float: right;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
.navbar.active {
  width: 100%;
}
.navbar-item {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  -webkit-transition-delay: .3s;
  transition-delay: .3s;
}
.navbar.active .navbar-item {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="header">
  <h2 class="title"><a href="#">Site Title</a>
      <li class="client-item"><a class="client-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a></li></h2>
</section>
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="navbar-list">
    <li class="navbar-item"><a class="navbar-link-left" href="#" target="_top">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar-item"><a class="navbar-link-left" href="#" target="_top">Store</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="navbar-list Right">
    <li class="navbar-item"><a class="navbar-link" href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar-item"><a class="navbar-link" href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-soundcloud"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar-item"><a class="navbar-link" href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar-item"><a class="navbar-link" href="/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar-item"><a class="navbar-link" href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar-item"><a class="navbar-link" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-apple"></i></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```