# how to make hover captions work at tap on touch screens

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created a gallery using just CSS that when a thumbnail is hovered on, the title slides into view. It sort of works on touch screens that if the button is touched and held, the title appears. I would like to make it so that a tap brings up the title and a second tap enters the gallery. I've tried all sorts of jQuery code but nothing seems to enable the second tap. I'd also wouldn't mind if it was one tap with a second or two delay to read the title before entering the gallery. I'm new to javascript and this site so I apologize if I don't ask this properly. Thanks for your help!

Here's my code:

```
<head>
  <script src="js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $("target").click(function(){ $(this).toggleClass("titleBox"); });
  </script>
</head>

<body ontouchstart="" class="no-touch">
 <div class="wrap">

 <!-- Define all of the tiles: -->

<div class="box">
 <div class="boxInner">
  <a href="buildings/colorclock.html">
    <img src="images/buildings/thumbs/06.jpg" alt="Color Clock House">
    <div class="titleBox">Color Clock House</div>
  </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="boxInner">
   <a href="buildings/treetriangle.html">
    <img src="images/buildings/thumbs/07.jpg" alt="Tree Triangle House">
    <div class="titleBox">Tree Triangle House</div>
   </a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>

<style type="text/css">
  body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }

.wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 10%;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  padding-bottom: 20%;
}

.boxInner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.boxInner img {
  width: 100%;
}

.boxInner .titleBox {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
  font-size: .9em;
  background: #fff;
  background-size: 105%;
  color: #A59E97;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}


body.no-touch .boxInner:hover .titleBox, body.touch    .boxInner.touchFocus .titleBox {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.boxInner:focus {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

Comment: I've answered **somehow** similar to your question. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36439255/jquery-triggering-fadein-and-fadeout-on-menu/36439437#36439437

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to solve the click once, activate hover, click twice to to open the link on touch screens. If anyone is interested in the code here it is.

```
 jQuery(function($) {
        $('.boxInner').on("touchstart", function (e) {
          'use strict'; //satisfy code inspectors
          var link = $(this); //preselect the link
          if (link.hasClass('hover')) {
              return true;
          } else {
              link.addClass('hover');
              $('a.taphover').not(this).removeClass('hover');
              e.preventDefault();
              return false; 
          }
      });
```